# What technology is best to simulate a static 2d/3d lattice structure?

Tags: osx, simulation

I have an important final year project where I need to create some software which displays simple 2d and 3d lattice structures. To be specific, artificial [spin ices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_ice). a,b,c (in the attached figure) are the exact structures I need to create.

I have tried using lammps but I am not sure if lammps has enough functionality for what I need to do. I really appreciate any insight/help.

My question for now is, what do you guys think is the best starting point for creating a structure like example (a) in the attached photo. I can figure out how to add the magnetic vectors after the original lattice structure is formed. (Note, I am on macOS)

[image: artificial spin ice structures]